# How to get running process in Lazarus

Tags: process, lazarus

I use Lazarus IDE and my question is:

How to get running process in Lazarus? (only in Lazarus)

this work is easy in delphi by http://forum.codecall.net/topic/72604-getting-running-processes-list/

Comment: That code should work fine on Lazarus on Windows. Please explain what problems you have getting that to run.

Comment: i add tlhelp32 unit to my project, and when i compile the code, the error window was shown that said: "The program can't start because toolhelp.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem"

Comment: And that works for Delphi, or are you compiling examples meant for win9x or so?

Answer (score 1):

I think the unit tlhep32 should be replaced with JwaTlHelp32.

This simple one button, one memo app works in laz v1.6:

```
uses ...windows, jwatlhelp32;

var ...Snapshot: THandle; pe: TProcessEntry32;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Snapshot := CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPALL, 0);
  try
    pe.dwSize := SizeOf(pe);
    if Process32First(Snapshot, pe) then
      while Process32Next(Snapshot, pe) do  memo1.Lines.Add(pe.szExeFile);
  finally
    CloseHandle(Snapshot);
  end;
end;
```